# Can I install mkusb in Ubuntu live USB?

Tags: live-usb

I want install mkusb in persistance live Ubuntu
COMRADE but I use mkusb in live usb Ubuntu not original Ubuntu so . How to install mkusb in persistance live usb(not original)

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu: You can install mkusb to a Persistent drive exactly the same as to an Installed drive, Latest instructions here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=95&p=13961108#post13961108

Comment: Great original question.

Answer (score 2):

### Installing mkusb and dus to Persistent USB

**Mkusb and dus** can be installed to Persistent USB exactly the same as to an Installed drive:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mkusb
sudo apt install usb-pack-efi
```

**Version dus and guidus seperately**

```
sudo apt install dus
sudo apt install guidus
```

Ref:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=95&p=13961108#post13961108