# Bootable USB not detected in Bootloader

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-10

I am weak in OS related knowledge. So apologies in advance if this feels a very silly question.

I have Ubuntu already installed in my Dell laptop. I am trying to install Windows 10. I dont want to do dual boot. I want to remove ubuntu and install windows 10.

1. I created a bootable usb by downloading iso file and then restore disk image. I refered tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiMUD9is-LA
2. I tried to reboot. The boot sequence manager shows my usb device but then I get error while installing
   `A media driver your computer needs is missing`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi ! For Win10, i never have been able to make a usb boot from Ubuntu, whatever way I used. I always had to use a Windows computer to make it. However, I didnt know about [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) at the time, maybe you could get a look at it

Comment: Those are old instructions for making a Windows installer. Nowadays windows ISO's are larger than 4GB. Try mkusb or mkusb-plug instead.

Comment: @B.duGaray I made a bootable usb from windows using windows media tool and rufus but then it the bootloader does not detetct my usb

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Can you explain in a little more detail as to should I have iso file copy-pasted in usb and then run `mkusb` or `mkusb-plug` or there is another way to use these commands ?

Comment: @HiteshSomani Please let me know if answer below is not sufficient. I recall Rufus also worked for me. but the installer drive must either be BIOS **or** UEFI. Which mode is your computer? For UEFI mode use Rufus default settings, GPT, UEFI, (non CSM), for BIOS mode use MBR, BIOS.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, Thanks. I earlier had rufus set to MBR while my drive was GPT. I changed it and now I have installed windows 10. Thankyou very much.

Comment: @Hitesh Somani Glad that it worked for you. I will add this as an answer so that this solution is on record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rufus USB drive for installing Windows.

Rufus will make USB drives for installing Windows.

Default settings for Rufus Windows installers is GPT, UEFI, (non CSM)

These settings will only work on a computer with a GPT partition table and UEFI booting.

For older computers that use a MSDOS partition table and BIOS booting Rufus offers MBR, BIOS settings

Answer (score 2):

### Installing Windows using mkusb 12.5.7

- Install mkusb: [Can I install mkusb in Ubuntu live USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250091/can-i-install-mkusb-in-ubuntu-live-usb/1250149#1250149)
- Click mkusb-plug icon to start and then proceed as follows:

[image]

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Step 3

[[image]]4]

Step 4

[image]

Step 5

[image]

Step 6

[image]

Step 7

[image]

Step 8

You should now have a USB installer ready to infect your computer with Windows