# Switching from an SSD to HDD, how will Grub behave?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I am going to replace the HDD in my dual-boot laptop with an SSD. I don't want to move my files, since everything I need is backed up to the cloud. This is what I plan to do:

1. Install a fresh copy of Windows 10 on the SSD.
2. Create a partition and dual-boot Ubuntu as usual using a Live USB.
3. Restore my files from the cloud.

Here is my only concern: The first time I put the SSD, what will happen when I power on the PC? Will everything be the way it is when I set up a new PC or will Grub boot-loader menu still open? How do I ask the PC to install Windows from the ISO file in my USB drive?

I know such questions have been asked here, but no-one has answered what exactly will happen when I power on my PC. I don't want any alternative methods or workarounds to move my data using third-party tools, as this is the only route I want to take.

Comment: In Windows you can use the **media creation tool** to make an installer USB, or you can also use Rufus or Ventoy in Windows. In Ubuntu **mkusb-plug** will make a Windows installer USB, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1250530/43926. I do not know how to just boot a Windows ISO file on a USB.

Comment: 1.) Will the HDD and the SSD coexist initially, as in, both will be attached? And when you are done with your plans, you intend to remove the HDD permanently? 2.) I have experience only with Ubuntu installer USBs. I know that the system can boot from these USBs, and the Ubuntu installer can do its work without any OS on any internal disk. Is this the case with the Windows installer USB as well? Can it boot, can it act as a standalone OS, like Ubuntu's?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system. How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is how it installs & you want all installs in same boot mode. New install will normally set itself as new default. If boot loader not correctly installed or in wrong boot mode, then UEFI/BIOS may go back to the grub entry to boot. Just be sure to have working Windows repair/recovery flash drive and Ubuntu live installer. Since you have good backups, then you should have no worries. Although I am not a fan of cloud backup, many use it.

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear. I am permanently replacing the HDD with an SSD. I can create the Windows and Ubuntu installer USB's. All I want to know is - if I make no software changes to my dual boot setup, and simply replace the HDD with an SSD, how will I be greeted on powering on the PC? And will the PC with no information in the new SSD be able to detect the installation USB?

Comment: For the first boot are you leaving the HDD plugged in? Are you keeping Ubuntu on the old HDD? Are the files on the cloud data files or program files? Will the SSD have a bootloader installed, which one? As long as the USB is bootable and set as the first drive, it should boot. Unplug the HDD with Ubuntu on it, while installing Windows, to stay safe.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I followed what you said, about unplugging the HDD with Ubuntu on it while installing Windows. I realized, on reading your comment, that this was the safest thing to do.
I was successful in doing what I wanted. Thanks!