# Use a Live Ubuntu Medium to make another Live USB Linux Medium?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb, system

I am currently on a live USB medium of UBUNTU. I am testing it, it is running from the USB, my RAM and what ever else is needed to run a live USB OS of Ubuntu.

Now I have another USB-stick of which I wish to use the full Linux Terminal that is currently loaded upon my computer of which I am using to type to you, so as to create a new live-USB of another Linux distribution.

Is this possible and if so how should I go about it?

I can download such distributions as Slackware, MX and/or Arch. I can us DD so as to copy it over to my other USB of which is formatted to a fat32. How should I do this and is this possible and if so, WHY?!?!?

To clarify Given the capabilities of Ubuntu, Debian, the live *NIX SYSTEM and other factors: Is it possible to boot into a live Ubuntu USB, connect another formatted USB stick to the same computer, format/modify the latter USB stick another Linux distribution (let us say it is lubuntu), restart the pc and install lubuntu?!?!?!

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking.  If why you can do this, a live Ubuntu USB has all capabilities of a full install OS, expect for keeping any changes or downloads when rebooted.  You can download a distro and burn it to other USB.  Will have to re-download distro if you reboot before burning.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic so slackware/MX/arch are off-topic unless the provide details useful in helping with your Ubuntu issue. If you have a Ubuntu issue, it's completely unclear (`dd` copies data and format is overwritten unless you're writing to a file and not partition/drive so your use of `dd` is itself unclear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Creating Live USB using Live USB.

Download the ISO's you want, (we will assume they are official Ubuntu flavors for now), and use the built in **Startup Disk Creator** to make more Live USB's.

You can set Firefox to save the downloads to your other USB or copy them there by hand later.

Better yet, download **mkusb** and create a persistent USB to work from. See: [Can I install mkusb in Ubuntu live USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250091/can-i-install-mkusb-in-ubuntu-live-usb/1250149#1250149) A Persistent USB can save you a lot of work.

**You can also make a SDC install Persistent on a by boot basis.**

Press shift at boot and esc, then F6 and esc again. then type a space and the word "persistent"

The session will persistent.

This must be done every boot where persistence in wanted.