# I am trying to make a Windows Install USB, but there are issues

Tags: boot, usb

Over the past few weeks, I've been trying to make a Windows installer USB by using WoeUSB/UNetBootin, but when I boot from the USB and click install, I get the error "`C:\Sources\install.wim`" is not found. So I do a bit of googling I found an answer, the post said that the .iso was corrupted. I download another Windows 10 ISO, reinstall it to the USB, boot from the USB & the error still persists, I tried installing Windows 7/8.1, and they too held errors like "BSOD" & "Format installer to FAT32" and "Media Drivers missing". I even tried to use the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool on a Windows 7 VM, but the USB drivers would not work. Now I am stuck with Linux for now.

Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: I understand that WoeUSB is not working in 20.04. mkusb-plug worked perfect for me.

Comment: If you use some formatting, line breaks and punctuation more people will read your  question to the very end. At the moment it's really hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

### Installing Windows using mkusb 12.5.7

- Install mkusb: [Can I install mkusb in Ubuntu live USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250091/can-i-install-mkusb-in-ubuntu-live-usb/1250149#1250149)
- Click mkusb-plug icon to start and then proceed as follows:

[image]

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Step 3

[[image]]4]

Step 4

[image]

Step 5

[image]

Step 6

[image]

Step 7

[image]

Step 8

You should now have a USB installer ready to infect your computer with Windows

**More Information can be found here:** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Comment: I tried this, it gets to a weird terminal thing and it doesnt look like its doing anyhting

Answer (score 0):

at first windows installation ability depend on putting `sources` drictory from windows iso to usb root directory. on the second hand you can make usb drive in ubuntu to install windows without any especial tool by 2 alternatives

1. format the USB drive to ntfs, extract windows 7/8/10/11 iso file to usb drive root and install grub2 to USB drive after mount usb drive in `/mnt`:

   `sudo -i`

   `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/sdx1/boot /dev/sdx  #make sure to sellect the right litter to replace with x`

add this menu entry to usb drive `boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
menuentry "Windows installation Environment" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  55DD0595418E5BFC
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 55DD0595418E5BFC
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
```

Replace `55DD0595418E5BFC` by your USB drive uuid that can be known from disk utility, save `boot/grub/grub.cfg` and reboot by your USB drive to install windows.

2. by other way you can extract hbcd pe 64 to usb root and install grub2 but extract install.wim from windows iso file to usb root ,add same menu entry from the first alternative, reboot by USB drive with hbcd and open winnetsetup program which uses install.wim to install windows.

related: [Create USB drive contains multi Ubuntu versions, HBCD-PE-64 and multi Windows installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474717/create-usb-drive-contains-multi-ubuntu-versions-hbcd-pe-64-and-multi-windows-in)