# create a Windows 10 bootable usb on Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb, windows-10

I am creating a windows 10 bootable usb on my system, ubuntu by following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwKp8E2xIAc

At 2m41sec, he says that the iso file can be downloaded from:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

and is 5MB. However, when I go on the website and download it, it is 5GB. So, I assume that I am not downloading the right file.

Could you please indicate me from where I can get this iso file ?

Comment: Typo in video, have right file.Windows ISOs round about 5GBs.  WinUSB should be changed WoeUSB or mkUSB.  If using license that came with computer or on another computer, need to use same version of Windows(home for home, pro for pro).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Instructions using **mkusb-plug** see:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268060/i-am-trying-to-make-a-windows-install-usb-but-there-are-issues/1268091#1268091 WoeUSB did not work for me last time I tried. mkusb-plug is very safe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded the right ISO. It could not be so little.

To write Windows 10 ISO to flash drive (tried on 20.04), you could try the following:

1. Install [WoeUSB](https://github.com/WoeUSB):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets3.0/libwxgtk3.0-0v5_3.0.4+dfsg-3_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i libwxgtk3.0-0v5_3.0.4+dfsg-3_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install woeusb
   ```
2. Write win10 iso using the following command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo woeusb --device path_to/Win10.iso /dev/sdX
   ```

   You could use `lsblk` and `blkid` commands to identify your flash drive device name for example, by name or by size:

   ```
   sdd      8:48   1  14.7G  0 disk 
   └─sdd1   8:49   1  14.7G  0 part
   ```
3. Maybe, the following also be helpful. Set boot flag on USB flash drive:

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sdd set 1 boot on
   ```