# Format Flash Disk Drive

Tags: 20.04, usb-drive, format

I need to reformat a 16GB flash drive.

It currently has Ubuntu 20.04 iso on it.  I need to erase the contents and put Windows 10 on it.

I found [this answer][1] that looked perfect, but when I tried it I got the message:

> This partition cannot be modified because it contains a partition
> table; please reinitialize layout of the whole device.
> (udisks-error-quark, 11)

Can someone advise me on my next step?

UPDATE:

Thank you for your kind attention.

Slow response.  I hope it comes back this time.

```
Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.
```

mkusb is not working out for me.

> please reinitialize layout of the whole device.

What is the proper way to do this?

I tried to do it with Disks by selecting the 16GB drive and asking to delete the partition.  I got an error message:

```
Error deleting partition /dev/sdb1: Failed to read partition table on device '/dev/sdb' (Invalid partition table - recursive partition on /dev/sdb.) (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

I **do not** want to install a bunch of stuff to do something so simple.  I would like to accomplish it with the Disks that ships with Ubuntu 20.04.

It has to be possible with Ubuntu.  What have I missed?

UPDATE:

Just found the USB flasher on my machine.  It appears to have written the Windows 10 iso to the flash drive without a problem.  I'll find out if it worked when I try to reboot my Windows 10 desktop tomorrow.

UPDATE: I'm typing this on my Windows 10 desktop.  The USB Flasher app wrote the .iso to the USB key perfectly.  Windows came right up.

I'm happy to have my Ubuntu laptop to rescue me.  I'm glad to have found the fix.  I'm grateful to those of you who took the time to try and help.

I wish I knew Linux and Ubuntu better.  Perhaps with more time I will.

Comment: Are you working in Ubuntu or Windows? If Ubuntu use Disks to unmount the drive, then use GParted to format the drive. I use mkusb-plug to make my Windows installers. Ventoy also works but is not as straight forward.

Comment: I have a Windows 10 desktop that needs a new boot iso after the automatic update failed and turned it into a brick.  I've downloaded the Windows 10 iso onto my Ubuntu laptop and need to put it on the flash drive so I can rescue my desktop.

Comment: My original problem still stands: I cannot format a flash drive.  Next steps seem like they'll be easy.

Comment: If you use mkusb-plug, you need ***not*** perpare the flash drive, need not format it, because mkusb-plug will overwrite whatever is on the drive. Just go ahead according to the answer by @C.S.Cameron.

Comment: Yet I cannot install mkusb, if you read the thread.   "Go ahead" - it failed every time I tried.  What next?

Comment: It sounds like your USB key may be broken. Most flash drives are guaranteed for a long time but I have never had any luck returning one.

Comment: @duffymo, is your problem solved now: Were you able to install Windows?

Comment: Yes, it is.  The USB key was fine.  USB Flasher from Ubuntu 20.04 did the job perfectly.

Comment: No, but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Installing Windows using mkusb-plug

- Install mkusb: [Can I install mkusb in Ubuntu live USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250091/can-i-install-mkusb-in-ubuntu-live-usb/1250149#1250149) Works on internal Ubuntu drives and on Live Ubuntu USB's
- Click mkusb-plug icon to start and then proceed as follows:

[image]

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Step 3

[[image]]4]

Step 4

[image]

Step 5

[image]

Step 6

[image]

Step 7

[image]

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Comment: Please see update.  Coulldn't get off the dime.

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa has always worked for me. See also the most recent info from the developer, sudodus, is here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=97&p=13968701#post13968701 Are you missin an "a" after the last "pp"?

Comment: Yes, I'm a bozo.  I missed the 'a' on the copy.  gpg key retrieve timed out after correction.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when formatting the flash drive.
I first `deleted` the Ubuntu partitions from the flash drive with `Disks` and then formatted it.

After formatting i used the `Disk Image Mounter` application and i copied the files mounted from windows iso to flash drive.

Comment: How do I delete the partitions using Disks?

Comment: I see the 16GB drive in Disks when I try to format, but it's not apparent when I try to delete the partition.

Comment: There are several partitions on a flash drive. Try deleting each partition separately.

Comment: Thank you.  I see two. I can't delete either one.