# Make Windows 10 bootable USB in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation

I'm trying to make a bootable USB from a Windows 10 iso. I have tried to use woeusb to do that, like the internet tutorials say, but even with the apt updated woeusb can't be located, nor does the version on the snap store works. So then I've mounted the iso and copied it's files into the USB.

That also didn't work, even manually selecting "boot from USB" the computer would just go straight to the linux install. I think that means that didn't work, even though I have used this same usb stick earlier today to install linux. What can be done?

EDIT: makeusb progress bar keeps going back once it is nearly done. Note that the rate is negative in the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Try with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Comment: I'm trying right now, but the progress bar seems to go backwards on and off, and it has been like this for a while. I've added a screenshot in the question.

Comment: When the write buffer is filled (more is written to the buffer than from the buffer) it goes backward. When the whole content of the iso file is written, the buffer will gradually get smaller. The buffered alias 'dirty' data will be written to the target drive. Finally all data will be written, and you will get information about that. The write speed to the target drive is usually limited by the memory cells of the USB pendrive.

Comment: Nautilus has a built-in ISO flasher. Did you try it?

Comment: If none of these solutions work for you, I would try Ventoy: https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html. It makes adding bootable ISOs to a USB drive as simple as copying the image to the drive.

Comment: eventually mkusb worked out, it just took a lot of time, I'm leaving the question in case somebody has the same issue

Comment: When a USB pendrive or memory card has been used for a long time it can get extremely slow at writing. Then it can help to wipe the whole device (overwrite with zeros), and the write speed will be restored to almost the original speed. You can do that with mkusb too.

Comment: Since the newer versions of Windows made the .wim file over 4GB, almost all instructions on Internet are wrong. You cannot then put the .wim file on a FAT32 partition. And FAT32 required for UEFI boot. The Windows tools split the .wim file. Do not know why Windows just does not split the file in the ISO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Installing Windows using mkusb-plug

- Install mkusb: [Can I install mkusb in Ubuntu live USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250091/can-i-install-mkusb-in-ubuntu-live-usb/1250149#1250149) Works on internal Ubuntu drives and on Live Ubuntu USB's
- Click mkusb-plug icon to start and then proceed as follows:

[image]

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Step 3

[[image]]4]

Step 4

[image]

Step 5

[image]

Step 6

[image]

Step 7

[image]

Step 8

You should now have a USB installer ready to infect your computer with Windows

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive