# How can I install Windows 10 on my Linux pc (Ubuntu 22.04)?

Tags: dual-boot

I have a Linux pc with 500 GB SSD and a 1Tb HDD.

The OS is Ubuntu 22.04 - and this is on the SSD.

I would like to install Windows 10 (which I have on a bootable USB) next to the Linux OS.

I should be grateful for help.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I boot from USB in Ubuntu, to install Windows 10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279901/how-do-i-boot-from-usb-in-ubuntu-to-install-windows-10)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but, no, this did not address my problem I did not want to replace Ubuntu - I wanted to add windows to my Ubuntu pc - on a separate (internal) drive. Archisman Panigrahi answered the question very nicely - see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disconnect the 500 GB SSD.
2. Boot from the Windows 10 live USB, and install Windows 10 on the 1 TB HDD.
3. Attach the SSD, and use UEFI settings to set it as the default boot.
4. Run the command `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu, so that it recognizes the Windows 10 installation, and allows the option to dual boot in the Grub menu.

Comment: Thank you very much. All went well until booted the Windows 10 live USB - the installation began but soon could progress no further because it said necessary drivers were not present. I could not proceed further. I confirm that the live USB works on my friend's Windows laptop. I wonder what driver/s it needs?

Comment: This is an Windows issue, and I really cannot help. Please ask a question in https://superuser.com/ for questions regarding Windows installation. You might be able to connect to WiFi so that the installer finds the necessary drivers, but I don't use Windows and cannot say much

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I managed to solve the issue by re-creating the Live-USB (Windows 10) using a friend's Windows pc - that booted just fine and the installation went well. I now have Windows on the HDD and Ubuntu on the SSD - independent of each other. The Windows installation messed with the Linux grub so that the pc automatically boots into  Windows. - I see there are suggested solutions on how to correct this and will attempt them when I have the mental strength!  In the meantime I just go into BIOS each time I want to use Linux and select that (the SSD).

Comment: Once again, many thanks for you time, expertise and patience - I really do appreciate it.
And, lastly, let me say that I seldom use Windows - only for Evernote really, as there is not an app available for Linux OS.

Comment: The "sudo update-grup" from the linux terminal solved the boot problem.
Thanks once again.