# How can I burn a windows 10 iso to an usb stick?

Tags: xubuntu

Can somebody help me trought teamviewer? I have ubuntu mate 20.04

Comment: Many old instructions are not valid as now Windows is over 4GB and requires larger flash drive. And newer Windows ISO has a .wim file that is over 4GB and will  not fit on FAT32 formatted partition. The Windows installer splits the .win file to have it fit. Using mkusb-plug: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274878/make-windows-10-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu

Comment: I also use mkusb-plug, mkusb-dus is also working. Yesterday I extracted a Windows 10 ISO, (Windows-1909.iso), to a NTFS partition on a persistent USB drive that was made using mkusb. and it booted right up in UEFI mode, no GRUB menuentry for Windows required. I am planning on testing if this also works on a regular USB

Comment: You do not need a USB stick to install Windows 10. I have just tried extracting the Windows 10 ISO to a freshly formatted NTFS USB drive. The Windows installer seems to run fine. I tried the same thing extracting the Windows 10 ISO to a NTFS partition on an internal Ubuntu hard drive, the Windows boot loader governed when booting. **No USB was needed to install Windows**.