# Unetbootin doesn't show windows 7 iso installer on the boot menu

Tags: boot, 20.04

I am on Ubuntu now,i downloaded unetbootin from their official website,downloaded the windows 7 ultimate iso image,formated the Pendrive with gParted to FAT32, burned it on my Pendrive(32GB),and i boot my pc from the pendrive the menu below shows up but there is only one option which is "Default"

[Image of unetbootin boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yciCE.png)

Thank you in advance if you respond to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

### UNetbootin and Windows

**UNetbootin does not do Windows.**

From a Windows computer you can use **Windows Media Creation Tool**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d

or **Rufus**

https://rufus.ie/

From an Ubuntu computer you can use **mkusb-plug**

[Make Windows 10 bootable USB in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274878/make-windows-10-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu/1274975#1274975)

or **mkusb-dus**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive