# How to set up Windows 10 partiton on Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I've downloaded the .iso image for the Windows 10 OS, and have imaged it to /media/windows and made it bootable and am using FAT16, and with the bootable option ticked. I restarted my computer, and the UEFI isn't showing and when i start the partiotion on disks, nothing happens.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: For UEFI boot & install, you need FAT32, but file cannot be over 4GB in FAT32. New versions of Windows use .wim file that is over 4GB, so old instructions do not work.See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274878/make-windows-10-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu
Split .wim with Linux tools.
https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-10-usb-media-linux.html
The .wim too large, Windows commands to split
https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln313422/windows-10-iso-contains-wim-file-that-is-big-for-fat32-file-system?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to use Windows10 for, one could argue that running it in a VM would be the simplest and most effective way to have Windows10 on an Ubuntu installation. That said, I'll assume you want to have Windows10 alongside Ubuntu. For that, you'll need to do this:

**0 — Write the Windows10 ISO to a USB Stick as a bootable device**

1. Use `df` to find your USB stick (it'll be something like `/dev/sdc` or some such) and it's mount point (eg: `/media/{user}/USB`)
2. Unmount the USB stick:
   `sudo umount /media/{user}/USB` (change this to whatever the actual mount point is)
3. Write the .iso file to the USB stick:
   `sudo dd if=windows10.iso \ of=/dev/sdc bs=1M status=progress` (be sure to change `windows10.iso` to the actual file name and `/dev/sdc` to whatever your USB stick happens to use)

**1 — Prepare an NTFS partition for Windows**

To install Windows 10, it is necessary to have a *primary* NTFS partition created on your machine. You can do this via GParted or Disk Utility. You'll probably want to delete that FAT16 partition that you created, as it's unnecessary.

**2 — Install Windows 10**

1. Start the Windows Installation from bootable DVD/USB stick
2. After entering the activation key, choose "Custom Installation"
3. Select the NTFS Primary partition that you created in Ubuntu

After a successful installation, Windows will replace the boot loader with its own thing, making it difficult to return to Ubuntu. Now you get to do this:

**3 — Install Grub for Ubuntu**

To install and fix grub, you'll need a Live DVD or Live USB of Ubuntu.

1. Boot into Live Ubuntu with the DVD or USB stick
2. Boot-repair will get automatically launched. Select "Recommended Repair"
3. Reboot

You will now have a Grub menu on boot, where you can choose from Ubuntu, memtest, and Windows 10.