# How to remove Ubuntu and get Windows back on?

Tags: 21.04

I have absolutely no experience with Linux, and I desperately need to get my computer back up and running again with Windows.

How do I remove Ubuntu and reinstall Windows?

Comment: Just install Windows. OSes don't need to be removed. At some point during the installation you'll be asked where to install, select and delete all the partitions and proceed. This has NOTHING to do with Linux or user's experience with it. This is ALL about installing Windows so hopefully you have enough experience with it.

Comment: If you need to make a Windows install disk using Ubuntu I suggest **mkusb-plug**. I tried the latest version of mkusb 12.7.1 with Win10_20H2_English_x64.iso last night and it worked perfect. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1274975/43926