# WoeUSB-ng does not stop unmounting and removing

Tags: boot, usb, woeusb

I'm trying to use woeusb to create a usb bootable windows 10. During the installation I have a load that seems infinite on the "Unmounting and removing /media/woeusb_target_1642606110_3688..." (I left it between 2 and 3 hours). When I cancelled I got a message that the installation was successful. Can I boot with the key or is this not normal?

Comment: WoeUSB has never worked for me. Mkusb works every time for me when making Windows installer drives. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1274975/43926