# When booting from windows usb it black screens with blinking cursor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

I was booting into a windows 10 bootable usb for the first time because my computer screen black screened whenever I started it up  saying `clean, 325264/14655488 files, 5730633/58607369 blocks` if you have an answer to that please say because I can get into the computer. when booting the bootable usb it had a blinking curser and that's it I also tried it on reinstalling ubuntu but it had the exact same thing?! I looked at some other forums and they didn't work or I did it wrong. I can still go into root and other things like that.

Comment: How did you make your installer USB?

Comment: I made it on a Mac with UNetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

### UNetbootin will Not Make a Windows Install Disk.

**and UNetbootin will not install Windows**

However you can make a persistent Ubuntu USB using UNetbootin on a Mac.

Then you can install **mkusb** to the persistent Ubuntu USB.

Next you can use mkusb-dus or mkusb-plug to create a Windows install disk on a second USB of at least 8GB. (Mkusb-plug is a little bit more foolproof than mkusb-dus).

[How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/1268092#1268092)

If you actually want to install a running version of Windows 10 to USB, you will need to use Rufus or Universal running on Windows and use their install Windows-To-Go option.

Comment: Can I get refus for a Mac?

Comment: You can get Etcher for a Mac, https://www.balena.io/etcher/, but it is not persistent. you can install mkusb and make your Windows installer, (or a persistent USB), but mkusb will be gone next boot.

Comment: Hello thanks for responding can you send a link to download mkusb for Mac. Thank you a lot

Comment: @Bentley100 There is no mkusb for Mac, but if you make a Ubuntu USB using UNetbootin for Mac, you can then boot that USB and download mkusb for Linux. Then you make your Windows USB using mkusb running on the USB..

Comment: Ok will do so. thanks

Comment: @Bentley100 this might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250091/can-i-install-mkusb-in-ubuntu-live-usb/1250149#1250149

Comment: Hello again, I just tried a ubuntu bootable usb and it came up with UEFI and just the normal usb. I clicked on the UEFI option and it came up with the normal boot screen. When I pressed the normal usb option it just came up with the black screen and the blinking curser. any answers?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "normal". To what number are you getting, 1) installing Ubuntu to USB. 2) Booting Ubuntu on USB. 3) Installing mkusb to Ubuntu on USB. 4) Using mkusb to install Windows ISO to second USB, 5) Boot Windows installer USB. 6) Install Windows.

Comment: When I mean normal usb it just says usb next to it not UEFI. so there is 2 option but they don't both work. and I have installed all the ubuntu files on there with the iso file tomorrow I will try 32 bit iso file   just to make sure its not just the iso file and that it can't read it.

Comment: If you want to install Windows in UEFI mode the Windows USB should be boot in UEFI mode, If you want to install Windows in Legacy mode the USB should be boot in Legacy mode.